# yii1 filter with multiple condition not working

Tags: gridview, filtering

I want to add multiple condition for my filtering condition,

default

> $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);

but how can i add multiple conditon like

> $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true && 'value',$this->value);

this is how i need to satisfy two condition for current result

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer for that check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/7416-cactiverecord-with-multiple-conditions-how/)